# Right Padding Issue Header- Building Responsive Design

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build responsive design page for desktop, mobile etc.

The header for each of the menu items is supposed to be right aligned. I have given zero margin but it still appears as I inspect the output in Chrome leading to the third menu item spilling over on the next line. What am I doing wrong?

Chrome Inspect Screenshot: Padding can be observed next to Chicken header[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZITrR.jpg)

Here is the code:

```css
/********** Base styles **********/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  width: 90%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
}
section{
  position:relative;
  margin:10px;
}
.menuItem{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; top:0%;left:80%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: grey;
  overflow-wrap:break-word;
  /*position: relative; top:1; right:1;*/
}
/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  /*width: 50%;*/
}

/********** Desktop only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** Tablets only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** Phones only **********/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/module2-style.css"/>
      <title>Assignment Solution for Module 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Our Menu</h1>
      <section class="row col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="menuItem">Chicken</div>
          <div>
            lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
            minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class="row col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="menuItem">Beef</div>
        <div>
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
        ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="menuItem">Sushi</div>
      <div>
      lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </div>
  </section>
    </body>
  </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1ad2ofu/

Comment: I don't get the same problem in Firefox (full size desktop), unless i disable your `width: 20%`; However i must say your markup is a bit weird for what currently seems like a pretty straight forward layout. Is the idea that it should look like it does now (2 columns of menu items except with a lot more than 3 menu items) ? And i assume by responsive you want the 2 columns to collapse down to 1 single column on smaller screen like tablets and phones ?

Comment: Thanks. I figured I was doing it the complex way.

Comment: :) If you're still stuck at the same point, and if my description above was correct, i can show you a quick way of getting the same layout using the flex features if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'spilling over' or related to margins, just the inspector highlighting that it's a block element that should be 100% the width of its parent to occupy the space.

Use `display: inline-block` on the `.menuItem`.

```css
.menuItem{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; 
  top:0%; left:80%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: grey;
  overflow-wrap:break-word;

  display: inline-block;
}
```